# Significance of tensors of the form $\mathbf A - \frac12 \mathbf g\operatorname{tr}\mathbf A$

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, tensor-calculus

In pseudo-Riemannian geometry and GR, constructions of the form $\mathbf A - \frac12 \mathbf g\operatorname{tr}\mathbf A$ seem common; for example

- $G_{ab} := R_{ab} - \frac12 g_{ab}R$, the Einstein tensor;
- $\hat T_{ab} := T_{ab} - \frac12g_{ab}T^c{}_c$, a modified stress–energy tensor appearing in an alternative form of the Einstein equations, $R_{ab} = -8\pi \hat T_{ab}$ (see (4.10) of [Witten](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03928) for example);
- Perhaps a non-example, but the stress–energy tensor of electromagnetism  $T_{ab} = F_{ac}F_b{}^c - \frac14 g_{ab} F_{cd}F^{cd}$ looks like a generalisation of this pattern—especially if one writes
  $$
  H_{ab} := F_{ac}F_b{}^c, \\
  T_{ab} = H_{ab} - \frac14 g_{ab} H_c{}^c.
  $$

What properties does $\mathbf A - \frac12 \mathbf g\operatorname{tr}\mathbf A$ have that makes it "special"?

---

Notice that if $\mathbf B := \mathbf A  - \frac12 \mathbf g \operatorname{tr}\mathbf A$ then, in four dimensions, $\operatorname{tr}\mathbf B = (1 - \frac12\cdot 4)\operatorname{tr}\mathbf A = -\operatorname{tr}\mathbf A$ is *trace-reversed*.
Why is this this such an important property that the Einstein tensor exhibits it?

Comment: For 4x4 matrices, the trace of the square of the trace-reverse is the trace of the square of the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

In arbitrary spacetime dimensions, the [Einstein tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor) is $$G_{\mu\nu}~:=~R_{\mu\nu}(\Gamma)-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}R_{\rho\sigma}(\Gamma).\tag{1}$$ 
Let us also define the Einstein [tensor-density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) 
$${\cal G}_{\mu\nu}~:=~\sqrt{|g|}G_{\mu\nu}. \tag{2}$$
It satisfies a functional [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations)
$$ \frac{\delta {\cal G}_{\mu\nu}(x)}{\delta g^{\rho\sigma}(x^{\prime})}
~=~ \frac{\delta {\cal G}_{\rho\sigma}(x^{\prime})}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}(x)}. \tag{3}$$
Eq. (3) means that there exists a functional $S$ [which not surprisingly happens to be the [Einstein-Hilbert (EH) action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) up to normalization] such that
$$ {\cal G}_{\mu\nu}(x)~=~\frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}(x)}.\tag{4}$$
Other linear combinations of the terms in eq. (1) [apart from an over-all normalization] do not enjoy the property (3) [and its consequences].

Comment: What is the meaning of the primes in (3)?

Comment: $x^{\prime}$ is just another spacetime point.

Answer (score 3):

Vary
$$S=\int \sqrt{\det g} g^{\alpha\beta} X_{\alpha\beta}$$
with respect to $g^{\alpha\beta}$ to get the index-down stress-energy tensor (assuming $X$ does not depend on $g$)
$$
\frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\alpha\beta}}= \sqrt{\det g} \left(X_{\alpha\beta}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta} X_{\gamma\delta}g^{\gamma\delta}\right)$$
so stress energy tensors for non-gravitational theories will be of this form. (Well, $\delta S/\delta g^{\alpha\beta}g^{\beta\gamma}$ is of the form you describe.)

There is also a perverse explanation: 2 dimensions are special, and matrices $A-{\rm tr}(A)/2$ are traceless if they are two-by-two; relatedly, the combination $\sqrt{\det g}g^{\alpha\beta}$ is of unit determinant (I'm assuming Euclidean signature here so the determinant is positive and I don't have to write a minus sign) in two dimensions, which is responsible for e.g. the Weyl invariance of the bosonic string.